# ngCordovaGoogleAnalytics works on ios, but doesn't on Android

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, google-analytics, ngcordova

I'm using [ngCordova Google Analytics plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git) in my ionic V1 app. I'm able to get it working for IOS and the data is shown in the GA console when I run my app in an IOS device. But the problem is, it does not seems to be working on Android devices. Nothing is shown in the GA console when I run my app on an Android device. I have waited 24 hours and still I can't see any data generated from Android devices. It does not give any errors as well. Following is how I initialise the GA plugin

In **app.js**

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaGoogleAnalytics) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (typeof window.analytics !== undefined){
          $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
          $cordovaGoogleAnalytics.trackView('Login Screen');
        }
       else {
          alert('cannot start');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a bug in the ngCordova wrapper for [danwilson's plugging for GA](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin#javascript-usage). I managed to solve this by using the original method to start tracker. So solution is simple, just do the following :

**replace**

`$cordovaGoogleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXX-X');`

**with this**

`window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXX-X');`